# JAXB marshalling to HTML throws exception in xsl:when using <a> tag

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, jaxb

I have this template

```
<xsl:when test="@width &gt; 500">
    <a href="{@path}"><xsl:value-of select="@path"/></a>
    <br/>
</xsl:when>
```

What I need to do is that when some xml image element has its width attribute larger then 500, I will not write  element and display it but I just write simple link to which user can click and view that image instead.

I am getting this error:

```
The element type "xsl:when" must be terminated by the 
matching end-tag "</xsl:when>".
```

And VM totally crashes after this.

However when I delete that closing  tag, it says that it needs that one, so I can not go without closing "a" element but it fails to render it.

Is there some workaround?

Comment: Looks fine. Are there other `xsl:when` elements in your code? What happens if you remove `<br/>` from the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was that I can not use that br tag which closes itself in connection with xsl:when ... totally stupid I would say.

Comment: Your XSLT code is fine and technically, having an empty element inside `xsl:when` is not a problem. If you reveal more context (input XML, entire XSLT code) I am sure we can find a way.